# Choosing a conformal map $\mathbb{H} \rightarrow \mathbb{D}$

Tags: complex-analysis

I am studying conformal maps and noticed the Cayley transform mapping the upper half plane to the unit disk comes up very frequently. However, I have noticed that the mapping used is not always the same (likewise for the inverse map $\mathbb{D} \rightarrow \mathbb{H}$). I have two questions regarding this

1. Is this not a contradiction of the Riemann mapping theorem, which states any conformal map from an open (simply connected and non-empty) set to a disk is unique?
2. Is the matter of which map to choose largely irrelevant? Or is it important to pay attention to where specific points are being mapped to, for example if one is solving Laplace's equation with certain Dirichlet conditions. How do these different maps differ?

Comment: There is no uniqueness (think of rotations mapping the unit disk to itself).

Comment: @ArcticChar I must have misunderstood the Riemann mapping theorem then which claims uniqueness, is this uniqueness pertaining to something else?

Comment: It's unique if you also specify $f(z_0)$ and $\operatorname{arg}f'(z_0)$ at some $z_0\in \Omega$.

Comment: @ArcticChar Thank you! That greatly clarifies the first question. Does this imply if I wanted to conformally map a domain $U$ onto a domain $V$, some part of which involves the map $\mathbb{H} \rightarrow \mathbb{D}$, then the choice of map is irrelevant?